# SSRS - How to control expanded group row height

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

SQL Server 2014
Using Report Designer in VS2015
We have a Tablix with 6 row groups.  (The first row group's column is hidden, as we have a page break for each instance in that group.)
When all groups are collapsed, the table appears to have the row heights as assigned in the .rdlc.
As soon as a group is expanded, the next groups have row heights with way too much whitespace.
Any ideas on how we can control that - the height of the expanded group row when sub-groups are still collapsed?

[image]

Comment: If you unhide the hidden group, does the cell size reflect the data in it? Normally cells will only expand to fit the content. You can also setting *[can grow] = false* in the cell properties.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks for the reply.  All TextBoxes have CanGrow set to false, and the content of every textbox fits easily in the size allotted.

Comment: Could it possibly be that there is a details group (without grouping) either in row groups or column groups?